# Python: array and print() format

Tags: python, list, format

I am trying to implement a function that changes array_1 to array_2, so that array_2 produces the same output as array_1. For example:

```
for item in array_1: 
    print(item, end ='')
```

I want the code below to produce the same output as the code above:

```
for item in array_2:
    print(item)
```

`array_1 = ["Hello", "World", '\n', '\n', "This", "is", '\n', "a", "textarray"]`

Running this through the first code gives me:

```
HelloWorld

Thisis
atextarray
```

How should I implement the function that changes array_1 to array_2 so that it produces the same output above?

Comment: `array_2 = array_1` maybe?

Comment: array_2 is undefined. I want to build array_2 from array_1 so it negates what print(item, end =' ') is doing and use print(item) instead.

Comment: Since `print` without the other parameters will force a newline at the end of the printing, you need to properly concatenate the elements of `array_1` into a single string.  Visit your favorite tutorial for information on basic string operations.

Comment: @Prune That still doesn't solve the problem, because there's still going to be one extra newline at the end of the loop. There really is no way around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all you're really looking for is to change the default behavior of `print` so that it doesn't output a trailing newline by default, you can use `functools.partial` to make `end=''` a default parameter instead. This way, you don't need to worry about creating a new list from `array_1`.

```
from functools import partial
print = partial(print, end='')
array_1 = ["Hello", "World", '\n', '\n', "This", "is", '\n', "a", "textarray"]
for item in array_1:
    print(item)
```

This outputs:

```
HelloWorld

Thisis
atextarray
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is impossible.

---

First, notice that the reverse direction would be easy. The difference is that the items in `array2` are printed with a newline after each one, while the items in `array1` are printed with nothing after each one, so all you'd need to do is add a `\n` to the end of each item in `array_1`.

```
array_2 = [item+'\n' for item in array_1]
```

---

You can't just reverse that. There's obviously nothing like `item-'\n'`. It every item happened to end with a `\n`, you could do `item[:-1]`, but most of them don't, and you can't remove a newline that isn't there.

And there's no way to cancel out the newline that `print` is going to add after the string with an `anti-newline`. I mean, you could include a terminal control sequence to move the cursor up one line so it kind of *looks* like it did the same thing, but it's not actually doing the same thing, and that would be ridiculously easy to break (run the code on Windows, redirect the output to a file, …).

---

You can get *pretty* close. You never said that you need the elements to be in one-to-one correspondence, so you can just do this:

```
array_2 = [''.join(array_1)]
```

Now you've just got one item in `array_2`, so the fact that it's printing newlines between the items doesn't matter.

---

But there's still a newline at the end, after all one items. And still no way to get rid of that (since the last item doesn't end in a `\n` that you can remove).

So, the problem is impossible. (Short of trick-question answers like redefining `print` to special-case your output or something.)

Comment: I am not necessarily trying to remove a newline. I am trying to format array_1 such that we can work around creating the newline.

Comment: @Corp.andLtd. I get that, and that's the point: There's no way to do that. The newline is added by `print`, it's not part of the strings. Therefore, nothing you can do to the strings will prevent the newline from being printed.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your program after you assign array_1 a value you can simply write `array_2 = array_1`.

Also make your first bit of code a function with the parameter x so you can put array_1 and array_2 alike. Your final code should be something like this:

```
array_1 = ["Hello", "World", '\n', '\n', "This", "is", '\n', "a", "textarray"]
array_2 = array_1
def arr(x):
    for item in x: 
        print(item, end ='')
```

Then you can vary putting array_1 or array_2 when sending this function.

```
arr(array_1)
arr(array_2)
```

These should give you the same values.